# How to set Stripe's subscription billing cycle to month end programmatically?

Tags: stripe-payments

As title, I am using Django's `djstripe` library, but I cannot find a way to make subscription to be charged month-end easily.

By default, if I issue

```
subscription = customer.subscribe(
                plan_stripe_id,
                charge_immediately=False,
                quantity=quantity)
```

The subscription billing cycle would start at the time the code executes. I want the subscription to charge at month end.

Is it a limitation of `djstripe` and I need to use other stripe python library like [stripe-python](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python)?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that's not implemented yet. Tracking [here](https://github.com/dj-stripe/dj-stripe/issues/658). Pull requests are welcomed.